# Saint-Louis (Haut-Rhin) train station to MLH/BSL?

Tags: france, airport-transfer, taxis, bsl

I [understand](http://www.distribus.com/uploads/ligne11.pdf) there's a bus every twenty minutes but that twenty minutes might just be too long. I am coming from [Mulhouse](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/stboard.exe/en?boardType=dep&REQProduct_list=1%3A1111111111000000&maxJourneys=20&start=1&distance=1&input=Saint-Louis+(Haut-Rhin),+Gare&selectDate=today&time=05%3A35) and if I catch the 08:48am train arriving to St Louis at 09:01am then there's a good chance of missing the 09:05 bus and my check-in closes at 9:30. An earlier train would be quite a bit earlier because it's slower. So I am trying to make a contingency plan and a taxi looks like it. Are there taxis at Gare Saint Louis? If so, where?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, [Google Street View](https://www.google.com/maps/@47.5910957,7.5556082,3a,75y,165.53h,105.76t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1sb92tk6LDFQaf7-LxwR2-xQ!2e0!7i13312!8i6656) answers this question: there are taxis in front of the station.

Edit: note the bus stop in this pic is *not* the airport bus. That's the other side of the station, at the end of a poorly marked maze. Also note you should avoid this airport like the plague the entire transport network is horrible (starting as far as from Zurich), the airport staff is jaded and doesn't speak English. The "fast track" security line is really meh. Just avoid.